# Deleting particular value from a cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a cookie "wishlist". It contains list of id's. I want to delete a particular id from cookie. I am deserialising the cookie but I am not able to remove particular id from it. The code that I am working on is as follows:

```
public int DeleteFromWishlist(long pid)
{
  List<Int64> ls_p = new List<Int64>();
  ls_p = Deserialize<List<Int64>>(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["wishlist"].Value));
  var prd = ls_p;
  foreach (var item in prd)
   {
     if (item == pid)
     {
         string it = item.ToString();
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["wishlist"].Values.Remove(it);
     }
   }
}
```

Now the above code is removing all the values from wishlist cookie.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Request.Cookies["wishlist"] != null)
{
    Response.Cookies["wishlist"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);   
}
```

And to delete particular item try below code(Just overwrite)

```
Response.Cookies["wishlist"].Values["YourItem"] = String.Empty;
```

Comment: This will delete the entire cookie. I only want to delete specific value from the cookie. wishlist cookie contains an array of integers and i want to delete a particular integer value.

Comment: See, i have values in my cookie in this form [3,4] and if i want to remove 4 from it. Your code is helping me remove 4 from the cookie but it's also replacing 4 with "=". So wishlist cookie now contains [3=] which isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from your list and then reset the cookie

Comment: How to remove? This is what i was asking for

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
  public int DeleteFromWishlist(long pid)
    {
        int result = 0;
        List<Int64> ls_p = new List<Int64>();
        HttpCookie mycookie = null;
        ls_p = Deserialize<List<Int64>>(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["wishlist"].Value));

        var prd = ls_p;

        {
            {
                ls_p.Remove(ls_p.FirstOrDefault(p=>p==pid));
                string data = SerializeItem<List<Int64>>(prd);
                mycookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["wishlist"];
                mycookie.Value = data;
                mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);
                result = 1;
            }

        }

        return result;

    }
```